# Are all matrices that fulfill $x^n-x=0$ are diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f(x)=x^n-x$ prove/disprove all matrices such that $f(A)=0$ are diagonalizable?

I have tried to find conditions on the minimal polynomial but it did not work, any suggestions?

Comment: What field are you working over?

Comment: @carmichael561 above R but if it true for C I will like to know

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f(A)=0$ then the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $f$, hence has distinct roots because $f$ does. This is enough to guarantee that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$ (look at the Jordan normal form).

Over $\mathbb{R}$, the stated condition is not enough to guarantee that the matrix is diagonalizable. For instance, if $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ then $A^5=A$, but $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why can we conclude that the are  distinct roots? Is it because $x^{n-1}=1 and above C it has n-1 distinct roots?

Comment: $x^n-x$ has no repeated roots because it is relatively prime to its derivative $nx^{n-1}-1$.

Comment: Or yes, for $\mathbb{C}$ you can just say the roots are $0$ and the $n-1$ different roots of unity.

Answer (score 4):

$f(x) = x^n - x = x (x^{n-1}-1)$ has no repeated roots.  The minimal polynomial of $M$ has no repeated roots, so $M$ is diagonalizable (over any algebraically closed field).

Answer (score 2):

Rotation by $120^\circ$ satisfies $x^4-x=0$, but is not diagonalisable over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: And we can take the rotation to be in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @6005 Or around a single axis in higher dimensions, I don't judge.